# How do I change the console log?

Tags: php, email

I use php to send email. It works perfectly, but I don't like that it outprints everything on the screen. I want this commant to remain silent. What should I do?
The command is the following:

verbose debug output

```
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '************@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*********';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('*********', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('**************.com');     
           


    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Want to get not';
    $mail->Body    = $_SESSION['nyelv'];
    $mail->AltBody = $_POST['email1'];

    $proba = $mail->send();
```

Comment: Is it posting all of your code to the screen? If so, then it's not processing your PHP at all

Comment: try this $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; will stop all warning/notice

Comment: It is working! thank you so much!

Comment: Great to hears that, but i wanw know what was the solution?